# AMP - show adsense test ads

Tags: adsense, amp-html

I am setting up AMP. I also want to add Adsense ads to it. I don't want to violate Adsense's policy, thus, what is the best way of displaying Adsense test ads while setting up an AMP news website? 
There is no note about it in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `examples` folder, there is one ad in test mode:

```
<h2>AdSense ad 2</h2>
<amp-ad width=300 height=250
  type="adsense"
  data-ad-client="ca-pub-2005682797531342"
  data-ad-slot="7046626912"
  data-adtest="on">
</amp-ad>
```

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/adsense.amp.html#L38

AdSense / Configuration
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/ads/google/adsense.md

When you want to disable test mode, I think you should *completely* remove `data-adtest="on"`